# Aggregate initialization of a derived class with designator

Tags: c++, initialization, c++20

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) we can know:

Since `C++17` for derived types:

> If the initializer clause is a nested braced-init-list (which is not an expression), the corresponding array element/class member /public base (since C++17) is list-initialized from that clause: aggregate initialization is recursive.

Since `C++20` for aggregate types:

Using `.designator = arg` to specify initialized members is no longer an extension to C, but is supported by the C++ standard.

```cpp
struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct B : A
{
    int c;
};

void test()
{
    A a{.a = 1, .b = 42}; // a.a = 1 && a.b = 42
    B b{{.a = 1, .b = 2}, 42}; // b.a = 1 && b.b = 2 && b.c = 42
}
```

Very simple and intuitive, right?

But let's complicate things a bit.

```cpp
constexpr int a_very_very_special_value = 42;

struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct B : A
{
    int c = a_very_very_special_value;
    int d;
};

void test()
{
    A a{.a = 1, .b = 42}; // a.a = 1 && a.b = 42
    B b{{.a = 1, .b = 2}, .d = 9}; // Ouch! Mixture of designated and non-designated initializers in the same initializer list is a C99 extension.
}
```

The above situation should be very common, we want a member data to keep its default value, but the standard requires us that `.designator = arg` must be after all parameters without `.designator`, but, this is impossible, how do we give our base a name? Like `.base_type_name = {.a = 1, .b = 2}`?

One might think that things like inheritance are totally unnecessary, we can do it like this.

```cpp
struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct B
{
    A base;
    int c = a_very_very_special_value;
    int d;
};

void test()
{
    A a{.a = 1, .b = 42}; // a.a = 1 && a.b = 42
    B b{.base = {.a = 1, .b = 2}, .d = 9}; // b.base.a = 1 && b.base.b = 2 && b.c = a_very_very_special_value && b.d = 9
}
```

Great, what else is unsatisfactory? Unless we have an interface like this.

```cpp
void test(A &a)
{
    if (a.a + a.b > 42) {
        std::cout << "42\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "0\n";
    }
}

void test()
{
    A a{.a = 1, .b = 42};
    B b{.base = {.a = 1, .b = 2}, .d = 9};

    test(a);
    test(b); // No matching function for call to 'test'
}
```

Those who are familiar with the memory model will definitely think that it is very simple, just add a forced type cast, anyway, the data of the original base class is in the head of the data.

```cpp
void test()
{
    A a{.a = 1, .b = 42};
    B b{.base = {.a = 1, .b = 2}, .d = 9};

    test(a);
//  test(b);
    test((A&)b);
}
```

However, one very important thing is that C++ supports multiple inheritance. If our original design idea is to form a complete type by inheriting multiple structures, what should we do?

Further, if our interface is separate for each inherited type, then we need to give a type cast method for all base classes, and also know the offset of the data in the type, if the data from the base class is not completely placed at the head of the class, the result will absolutely be wrong.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using constructors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've discovered, you can't use both designated initialization and also name the base class. In order to do that, the language needs to be extended to support that case. See [P2287R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2287r1.html), which I have not finished yet. Unfortunately, won't make C++23.

Until the language directly supports designated the base class (or directly designated members of the base class), if you want to use designated initializers your best bet is to have the base classes as members, as you've clearly documented.

Comment: Please remind me to buy you a beer or two when this finally makes int into STD. It was such an oversight to not include something so simple in C++20. Did they simply copy what was already available in C for ages with no extra thought?